# rbind.fill columns of different classes

Tags: r, date

After battling the strangest behavior of dates in R, where I was unable to manipulate dates without getting tons of error messages. I finally realized that the two data frames which I merged using the plyr::rbind.fill function stored their date in different classes. One was Date, the other character. This was so hard to detect because the date strings were converted into some type of NA which does not trigger the usual is.na() test! My question by now is more fundamental about the nature of the date and what function could detect it. (One method is to convert to integers.)
Here is a minimal example that illustrates the merging problem:

```
library(plyr)
x1=cbind.data.frame(Date=Sys.Date()+(1:5), x = sample(letters,5))
x2=cbind.data.frame(Date=Sys.Date()+(6:10), y = sample(letters,5))
(y1 =plyr::rbind.fill(x1,x2))

#           Date    x    y
#  1  2015-05-02    k <NA>
#  2  2015-05-03    o <NA>
#  3  2015-05-04    n <NA>
#  4  2015-05-05    v <NA>
#  5  2015-05-06    m <NA>
#  6  2015-05-07 <NA>    z
#  7  2015-05-08 <NA>    s
#  8  2015-05-09 <NA>    f
#  9  2015-05-10 <NA>    q
#  10 2015-05-11 <NA>    w

x2$Date=as.character(x2$Date)
(y2 =plyr::rbind.fill(x1,x2))

#           Date    x    y
#  1  2015-05-02    k <NA>
#  2  2015-05-03    o <NA>
#  3  2015-05-04    n <NA>
#  4  2015-05-05    v <NA>
#  5  2015-05-06    m <NA>
#  6        <NA> <NA>    z
#  7        <NA> <NA>    s
#  8        <NA> <NA>    f
#  9        <NA> <NA>    q
#  10       <NA> <NA>    w

sum(is.na(y2$Date))
#  [1] 0

is.null(y2$Date[6])
# [1] FALSE

is.na(y2$Date[6])
# [1] FALSE

class(y2$Date[6])
# [1] "Date"
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what the problem is. Waht is wrong with `y1`? The first column is of class `Date`, isn't it what you want? Creating `y2` you combine in the Date column Date-class and character-class, which results in Date-class, while character values are converted to NA's of class Date.

Comment: The problem is that my usual method of detecting NAs with is.na() does not work here. (Also, why wasn't the character class converted to Date?)

Comment: In R, a vector (and a column of a data frame is a vector) must be of the same type. When you attempt to combine different types they will be coerced to the most flexible type: logical -> logical -> integer -> double -> character, and a Date is of type double, so they are all converted to character.

Comment: Yes, that is what I expected, but as you can see, rbind.fill did NOT choose the more general character class, instead it coerces the column to be of Date class AND does not convert the string parts properly into Dates.
Imagine millions of records and not being able to use is.na() to detect the "bad" entries.

Comment: Date *is* character, you can check it by `typeof(y2$Date)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not fully aware of the difference between class and typeof ! I still find it strange that rbind.data.frame shows a very different behaviour: 
 `x2=cbind.data.frame(Date=as.character(Sys.Date()+(6:10)), x = sample(letters,5), stringsAsFactors=F) `
`(y3 =rbind.data.frame(x1,x2)) `
`class(x2$Date)`
`class(y3$Date)`
`typeof(y3$Date)`

Answer (score 0):

You may either convert the `Date` columns of both data.frame to either `character` or `Date/time` via `as.POSIXct`

```
> library(plyr)
> x1b <- x1 <-
+   cbind.data.frame(Date=Sys.Date()+(1:5), x = sample(letters,5))
> x2b <- x2 <-
+   cbind.data.frame(Date=as.character(Sys.Date()+(6:10)), y = sample(letters,5),
+                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> str(x1)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Date: Date, format: "2015-05-02" "2015-05-03" ...
 $ x   : Factor w/ 5 levels "j","k","l","v",..: 1 3 4 5 2
> str(x2)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Date: chr  "2015-05-07" "2015-05-08" "2015-05-09" "2015-05-10" ...
 $ y   : chr  "r" "v" "t" "m" ...
> (y1 <- plyr::rbind.fill(x1,x2)) # rbind keeps the colClasses in the first variable
         Date    x    y
1  2015-05-02    j <NA>
2  2015-05-03    l <NA>
3  2015-05-04    v <NA>
4  2015-05-05    z <NA>
5  2015-05-06    k <NA>
6        <NA> <NA>    r
7        <NA> <NA>    v
8        <NA> <NA>    t
9        <NA> <NA>    m
10       <NA> <NA>    c
Warning message:
In as.POSIXlt.Date(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
>
> ## convert both to character
> x1b$Date <- as.character(x1b$Date)
> (y2 <- plyr::rbind.fill(x1b,x2))
         Date    x    y
1  2015-05-02    j <NA>
2  2015-05-03    l <NA>
3  2015-05-04    v <NA>
4  2015-05-05    z <NA>
5  2015-05-06    k <NA>
6  2015-05-07 <NA>    r
7  2015-05-08 <NA>    v
8  2015-05-09 <NA>    t
9  2015-05-10 <NA>    m
10 2015-05-11 <NA>    c
>
> ## convert both to Date/time
> x2b$Date <- as.POSIXct(x2b$Date)
> (y3 <- plyr::rbind.fill(x1,x2b))
            Date    x    y
1     2015-05-02    j <NA>
2     2015-05-03    l <NA>
3     2015-05-04    v <NA>
4     2015-05-05    z <NA>
5     2015-05-06    k <NA>
6  3919836-01-29 <NA>    r
7  3920072-08-18 <NA>    v
8  3920309-03-10 <NA>    t
9  3920545-09-28 <NA>    m
10 3920782-04-19 <NA>    c
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don'understand but I do not see any errors. `x1` and `x2` are data frames with column  classes given by date and factor. When you use rbind.fill it must fill the row and in order to do so it pick up the class of the column it is about to fill in this case `factor` that's why you see `<NA>`.

With dates the behavior is a little bit strange I do not know why that happens the  Note section of ?as.Date is not clear.

To solve this you can use the following code, even though I am aware that it is not a very classy solutions... it works.

```
 is.na(as.character(y2[[1]]))
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```